# How to search a json with jq for values?

Tags: json, jq

I have a json of this structure:

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "60e327ee58a0": {
      "nodeinfo": {
        "network": {
          "mesh": {
            "bat0": {
              "interfaces": {
                "wireless": [
                  "<mac-address-removed>"
                ],
                "tunnel": [
                  "<mac-address-removed>"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "mac": "<mac removed>",
          "addresses": [
            "<ipv6 removed>",
            "<ipv6 removed>"
          ]
        },
        "hardware": {
          "model": "TP-Link TL-WR841N/ND v10",
          "nproc": 1
        },
        "software": {
          "batman-adv": {
            "compat": 15,
            "version": "2015.1"
          },
          "autoupdater": {
            "branch": "stable",
            "enabled": true
          },
          "firmware": {
            "release": "v2016.1+1.0.1",
            "base": "gluon-v2016.1"
          },
          "status-page": {
            "api": 1
          },
          "fastd": {
            "enabled": true,
            "version": "v17"
          }
        },
        "hostname": "Antoniusweg12",
        "system": {
          "site_code": "ffmsd03"
        },
        "node_id": "60e327ee58a0"
      },
      "lastseen": "2016-04-14T12:39:04",
      "flags": {
        "gateway": false,
        "online": true
      },
      "firstseen": "2016-03-16T15:14:04",
      "statistics": {
        "clients": 1,
        "gateway": "de:ad:be:ef:43:02",
        "rootfs_usage": 0.6041666666666667,
        "loadavg": 0.09,
        "uptime": 1822037.41,
        "memory_usage": 0.8124737210932025,
        "traffic": {
          "rx": {
            "packets": 50393821,
            "bytes": 5061895206
          },
          "forward": {
            "packets": 173,
            "bytes": 17417
          },
          "mgmt_rx": {
            "packets": 47453745,
            "bytes": 6623785282
          },
          "tx": {
            "packets": 1205695,
            "bytes": 173509528,
            "dropped": 5683
          },
          "mgmt_tx": {
            "packets": 37906725,
            "bytes": 11475209742
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "30b5c2b042f4": {
<next block...>
```

And I want to query it with jq for the hostname, the mac or the IPv6.

```
cat nodes.json |jq -c '.nodes[] | select(.nodes[]| contains("Antoniusweg12"))'
```

Most examples do not fit this kind of json structure as the objects have an index

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're going to filter, you need to drill down to the property that you want to check for and see if it matches your criteria. You can't expect to just give a name and you'll magically be presented with the results you want.

Searching by hostname, it is found on the `.nodeinfo.hostname` property of each node:

```
$ jq -c --arg hostname "Antoniusweg12" \
'.nodes[] | select(.nodeinfo.hostname == $hostname)' nodes.json
```

Similarly for the mac address, it's found on the `.nodeinfo.network.mac` property:

```
$ jq -c --arg mac "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff" \
'.nodes[] | select(.nodeinfo.network.mac == $mac)' nodes.json
```

For the ip addresses, there's an array of them but it's not that much different in the query.  They're found on the `.nodeinfo.network.addresses` property:

```
$ jq -c --arg ip "aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::1" \
'.nodes[] | select(.nodeinfo.network.addresses[] == $ip)' nodes.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on the question.  Suppose you want to find all occurrences of the key "hostname" for which the value is "Antoniusweg12",
no matter where the key/value combination occurs.

The following will reveal the path to the key/value combination of interest:

```
paths as $p
| select ( $p[-1] == "hostname" and getpath($p) == "Antoniusweg12" )
| $p
```

The result for the given input JSON:

```
[
  "nodes",
  "60e327ee58a0",
  "nodeinfo",
  "hostname"
]
```

If you wanted the path to the containing object, then replace the final `$p` with `$p[0:-1]`; and if you want the containing object itself:  `getpath($p[0:-1])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which searches for nodes where the specified `$needle` is present in any of the `addresses`, `mac` or `hostname` fields.

```
  "<ipv6 removed>" as $needle   # set to whatever you like

| foreach (.nodes|keys[]) as $k (
     .
   ; .
   ;    (      .nodes[$k].nodeinfo.network.addresses?
         + [   .nodes[$k].nodeinfo.network.mac?
             , .nodes[$k].nodeinfo.hostname?
           ]
        ) as $haystack

     | if $haystack | index($needle)
       then {($k): .nodes[$k]}
       else empty
       end
  )
```

EDIT: I now realize a filter of the form `foreach E as $X (.; .; R)` can almost always be rewritten as `E as $X | R` so the above is really just

```
  "<ipv6 removed>" as $needle

| (.nodes|keys[]) as $k
| (      .nodes[$k].nodeinfo.network.addresses?
   + [   .nodes[$k].nodeinfo.network.mac?
       , .nodes[$k].nodeinfo.hostname?
     ]
  ) as $haystack

| if $haystack | index($needle)
  then {($k): .nodes[$k]}
  else empty
  end
```